# TPL Dataflow async scheduling

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, tpl-dataflow

The scheduling of `async` `Task`s does not work as I expected in TPL Dataflow. In the example below, I expected the `ActionBlock` to process data from the `TransformBlock` as soon as it is available. But it is waiting on the second (delayed) result before it proceeds to the third. What have I misunderstood here? Is there some requirement on the order of processing?

```
public class TestDataFlow
{
    public System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

    public async Task Flow()
    {
        watch.Start();

        var plus10 = new TransformBlock<int, int>(async input =>
        {
            if (input == 2)
            {
                await Task.Delay(5000);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Exiting plus10 for input {0} @ {1}", input, watch.Elapsed);
            return input + 10;
        },
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4,
        });

        var printSolution = new ActionBlock<int>(input =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Solution: {0} @ {1}", input, watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliSeconds);
        },
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4,
        });

        plus10.LinkTo(printSolution);

        List<int> inputs = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
        foreach (var input in inputs)
        {
            await plus10.SendAsync(input);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exiting plus10 for input 1 @ 115.8583
Exiting plus10 for input 3 @ 116.6973
Solution: 11 @ 126.0146
Exiting plus10 for input 2 @ 5124.4074
Solution: 12 @ 5124.9014
Solution: 13 @ 5126.4834
```

Comment: Take a look at this my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38865414/799007) about making the mesh ignore keeping order

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TPL Dataflow guarantees order of the input and output queues no matter how many items are processed in parallel.

> "Because each predefined source dataflow block type guarantees that messages are propagated out in the order in which they are received, every message must be read from the source block before the source block can process the next message"

From [Dataflow (Task Parallel Library)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you want items to move on to the next block exactly when they are finished processing you should transfer them explicitly yourself which turns your `TransformBlock` to an `ActionBlock`:

```
var printSolution = new ActionBlock<int>(input =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Solution: {0} @ {1}", input, watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliSeconds);
},executionDataflowBlockOptions);

var plus10 = new ActionBlock<int>(async input =>
{
    if (input == 2)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Exiting plus10 for input {0} @ {1}", input, watch.Elapsed);
    await printSolution.SendAsync(input + 10);
}, executionDataflowBlockOptions);
```

Answer (score 3):

As of (at least) `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.4.6.0`, `ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions` now has a property `EnsureOrdered` which may be set to `false`.

To update:

```
Install-Package System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow
```

Code:

```
var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions {
  EnsureOrdered = false
};
var transform = new TransformBlock<int, int>(i => Transform(i), options);
```

Some more examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38865414/625919

Development history, which I thought was neat: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/536 https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/5191